# PDO and While function in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey guys so i really have a problem in php and i have been working on it for like an hour and i can get it to work. So in my database i have two tables:

usuarios and menus

So each user have a menu assigned like this:

usuarios 
id email ....... menus
1   email ...... 1,2,3,4

where   1,2,3,4    is text that i will explode and convert it into an array so latter i can get the menus checking the menu id's.

menus
id   url      .....
1    profile  ..........
2    messages ..........
3    log out  ..........
4    support  ..........

I dont know why it is not working, please help.

```
        <?php
        if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
          include_once "database.php";
          $section = !empty($_GET['s']);
            try {

              $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:usuid");
              $stmt->execute(array(':usuid'=>$_SESSION['id']));}


    // Checks the user id from his session (session has been already started in headers)       

              if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

              $row = $stmt->fetch();

              $menus = $row['menus'];

    //Gets the menus

              $menus = explode(",", $menus);

    //Converts the text into an array.


                $i = 0;
                $menusize = sizeof($menus);

    //Checks how big is $menus array 

                $menusize = $menusize -1;

    //This is because $i=0 and not 1

      while ($i == $menusize) {
          try{
                  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE id=:menus");
                  $stmt->execute(array(':menus'=>$menus[$i]));
                  $row = $stmt->fetch();

                      if ($section==$row['url']) {
                            echo '<li class="liselected"><a href="?s='.$row['url'].'"><i class="'.$row['icon'].'"></i><p>'.$row['name'].'</p></a></li>'; 
                      }else{
                            echo '<li class="menuelement"><a href="?s='.$row['url'].'"><i class="'.$row['icon'].'"></i><p>'.$row['name'].'</p></a></li>';

                      }

                      $i++;

              } catch(PDOException $e) {
                  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
              }                      
        }

//Here is the problem, in this while




              } else {


              }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }


        }else{
          header("Location:index.php");
        }
    ?>
```

I have checked and what happends is that $i doesnt seems to be incrementing, i have been working on it but nothing seems to do it.

Thank you all for your support!

Comment: Should `$i > $menusize` be `$i < $menusize`? It'll never run now, because you're starting with a value of 0.

Comment: Oh sorry, it should say =

Comment: I have edited that part of the code, still, it's not working.

Comment: Try `while ($i == 0)` instead. `$i = 0` is setting the value to 0, instead of comparing it.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks! I dindt see that one, still not working....

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out the logic here. When should your `while` statement actually run? How long should it run for?

Comment: $menusize represent how many menus the user has, so let say he have 4 menus the while function should run 4 times to get those menus from the menus table. @andrewsi

Comment: Then you need something like `while ($i < $menusize)`. If that isn't working, can you do some debugging and work out why not? Add some echos and see if the `while` runs at all; if it doesn't see why not, and if it does, check the SQL you're generating.

Comment: You might also be able to simplify the whole thing; you can select all a user's menu with a single `IN` clause.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, working on it right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it a little bit differently altogether, like storing the menu's in different rows but for now:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        include_once "database.php";
        $section = !empty($_GET['s']);
        try {
            # When you set the $_SESSION['id'] and you're sure it's sanitized you don't have to prepare a query. Instead execute it directly.
            # Preparing is useful for user submitted data or running the same query more then once with different values (seen below)
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:usuid");
            $stmt->execute(array(':usuid'=>$_SESSION['id']));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            // This part of the code does not match your description of your database.
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            $menu = explode(",", $row['menus']);
            // end
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE id=:menus");

            try{
                foreach($menu as $value){
                    $stmt->execute(array(':menus'=>$value));
                    $row = $stmt->fetch();

                    $css_class = ($section == $row['url']) ? 'liselected' : 'menuelement';

                    echo '<li class="'.$css_class.'"><a href="?s='.$row['url'].'"><i class="'.$row['icon'].'"></i><p>'.$row['name'].'</p></a></li>'; 

                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

Please note that I only prepared the query *once*, this is the proper way to do it. Preparing takes server performance, but once prepared you can rebind the values.

Also, I changed the loop to a foreach loop, easier to maintain.
There where also some bracket issues in the code, my advice always code in the same way so these issues are easy to spot.

Comment: The only suggestion I'd make would be to use an IN statement, so you avoid the `foreach` entirely; but that does need more code rewriting.

Comment: In the question it states he used multiple rows for menu's in the database, his code says otherwise. To avoid any issues of *this code does not work* I kept it as close to the original code. But yeah, in clauses in this case would proof useful.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i will be testing it like this. I think the problem may be int the PDO's of my code. This may fix it. Going to try it right now!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and support!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!! I am still new to PDO's and they are more confusing than using plain sql queries...